# My sorting algorithm doesn't work

Tags: algorithm, sorting, haskell

As homework, we were supposed to implement a few functions and then come up with a sorting algorithm potentially implementing those functions. first of all, these are the two needed functions:

```
remove :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a] 
remove a (x:[]) = x:[]
remove a (x:xs) =
  if a == x
    then xs
    else x:(remove a xs)
```

and:

```
smallest :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
smallest (x:y:[]) =
  if x < y
    then x
    else y
smallest (x:y:xs) =
  if x < y
    then smallest (x:xs)
    else smallest (y:xs)
```

My sorting Algorithm is just supposed to take the smallest element and put it at the beginning of the list:

```
sort :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a]
sort [] = []
sort x = smallest x : sort (rest x)
      where
        rest = remove (smallest x) x
```

The Error I get is

- Couldn't match expected type ‘[a] -> [a]’ with actual type ‘[a]’
- The function ‘rest’ is applied to one argument,
  but its type ‘[a]’ has none
  In the first argument of ‘sort’, namely ‘(rest x)’
  In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘sort (rest x)’

I'm surely missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what it is. help me pls.

Comment: It's defined in the where block

Comment: Notice, after it's fixed, the algorithm appears to sort and deduplicate the list.  `sort [1,1,1,1] == [1]`.  This is because `remove` removes all matching elements instead of just one.

Comment: But you call `rest x`, but `rest` is defined without any arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `remove` function will error on the empty list, and never remove an element from a list with *one* element. You probably want to write:

```
remove :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a] 
remove a [] = []
remove a (x:xs) | a == x = xs
                | otherwise = x : remove a xs
```

Next your `smallest` behaves weird as well since it will not select the smallest from a list with *one* element (in that case the smallest element is that case). We can rewrite it like:

```
smallest :: Ord a => [a] -> a
smallest [x] = x
smallest (x:y:xs) | x < y = smallest (x:xs)
                  | otherwise = smallest (y:xs)
```

Now that we have fixed these, we can focus on the real sorting function. I do not really see why you want to use a helper function here to remove the element, you can use a variable `small` to store the smallest element in the list, and then simply use recursion, like:

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort [] = []
sort x  = small : sort (remove small x)
    where small = smallest x
```

Now with this sorting algorithm, we obtain:

```
*Main> sort [1,4,2,5]
[1,2,4,5]
*Main> sort [1,4,2,5,1,3,0,2]
[0,1,1,2,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Compile Error

If we look at the entire error message from ghci, which is:

```
    * Couldn't match expected type `[a] -> [a]' with actual type `[a]'
    * The function `rest' is applied to one argument,
      but its type `[a]' has none
      In the first argument of `sort', namely `(rest x)'
      In the second argument of `(:)', namely `sort (rest x)'
    * Relevant bindings include
        rest :: [a]
          (bound at ...)
        x :: [a]
          (bound at ...)
        sort :: [a] -> [a]
          (bound at ...)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

We see that `rest :: [a]`.
But you are attempting to apply something to `rest` here:

```
sort x = smallest x : sort (rest x)
```

But you had already applied `x` here:

```
rest = remove (smallest x) x
```

So, simply change the former to:

```
sort x = smallest x : sort rest
```

And it will compile. That said, I haven't checked the logic of the algorithm itself.

### Fixing the logic:

I rewrote the code with the `LambdaCase` extension which looks neater.
I also renamed your sorting function to `sort'` so that it doesn't clash with `Data.List (sort)`.

You had 2 problems in `sort'`. First, you didn't handle the case of a singleton list, which resulted in a non-exhaustive pattern match. I added the clause `[x] -> [x]` for this. Second, you should use a `let` binding to evaluate `smallest xs` only once, I fixed that too. Third, you had the problem that Thomas M. DuBuisson described, which I fixed. And below is the code, with `quickCheck` and all.

```
remove :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a] 
remove a = \case
  []     -> []
  (x:xs) -> if a == x then xs else x : remove a xs

smallest :: Ord a => [a] -> a
smallest = \case
  (x:y:[]) -> if x < y then x else y
  (x:y:xs) -> if x < y then smallest (x:xs) else smallest (y:xs)

sort' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort' = \case
  [ ] -> [ ]
  [x] -> [x]
  xs  -> let s = smallest xs in s : sort' (remove s xs)

prop_sort :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
prop_sort xs = sort xs == sort' xs
```

Running QuickCheck:

```
> quickCheck prop_sort
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

With the alternate changes proposed by Willem Van Onsem, `smallest, sort` instead looks as:

```
smallest :: Ord a => [a] -> a
smallest = \case
  [x]      -> x
  (x:y:xs) -> if x < y then smallest (x:xs) else smallest (y:xs)

sort' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort' = \case
  [] -> []
  xs -> let s = smallest xs in s : sort' (remove s xs)
```

`smallest` can also be written as a fold:

```
import Data.List (foldl1)

smallest :: Ord a => [a] -> a
smallest = foldl1 $ \x y -> if x < y then x else y
```

and even shorter with by also using `min :: Ord a => a -> a -> a`:

```
import Data.List (foldl1)

smallest :: Ord a => [a] -> a
smallest = foldl1 min
```

wherefore our solution can be written, in total as:

```
sort' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort' = \case [] -> [] ; xs -> let s = foldl1 min xs in s : sort' (remove s xs)
```

Comment: Ok cool, progress. Now it compiles, but it prints an array with infinite "1"s

Comment: With what input?

Comment: sort [100,99..1], it just takes the last element and repeats it

Comment: JohnDoe, that's because you don't both removing the smallest element when its at the end: `remove a (x:[]) = x:[]`.

Comment: @JohnDoe updated my answer with a fix to the logic. Bear in mind that this algorithm is slow with complexity `O(n^2)`. A better solution is quicksort or mergesort. https://smthngsmwhr.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/sorting-algorithms-in-haskell/